# AX 2012 CU2 Conditional action for drill through reports

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to show one of the two simple reports on a click event. I have three report designs in a single Dynamics SSRS reporting project. One pie and two table designs. I want to show one of the table based on the user selection on pie slice. When I try to add conditional function for report action on the pie series I get compile time error stating that it is not allowed.

Action on series properties is set to "Go to report" and expression is set to ReportPrj.AutoDesign1 only this works, if I try to use a conditional query for my expression this fails to compile.

[=IIf(Parameters!pvalue.Value = 1, "ReportPrj.AutoDesign1", "ReportPrj.AutoDesign2")]

Matter of fact anything other than ReportPrj.Design format fails to compile. Is this some kind of limitation on AX SSRS reports. If that is the case what are my other options.

Here is the compile error.

***ReportPrj.AutoDesign1Pie.: Could not resolve drillthrough target report =IIf(Parameters!pvalue.Value = 1, 
        "ReportPrj.AutoDesign1", 
        "ReportPrj.AutoDesign2"
    ).***

I am running Dynamics AX 2012 CU2, SQL Server 2008 R2, and Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 2008 Server.

All you help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
mm

Answer (score 0):

Is that a valid expression with the starting "[" and ending "]"?

Does this work?

=IIf(Parameters!pvalue.Value = 1, "ReportPrj.AutoDesign1", "ReportPrj.AutoDesign2")